# MicrosoftWebDriver.exe should be pre-installed in an elevated command prompt

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I have microsoft edge installed on my machine with below versions:

```
Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363
```

I am trying to use `webdrivermanager` to run my automation test (`java+selenium`) on `Edge` by the below code:

```
WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

But, it complains with the below error:

```
WebDriverManagerException: MicrosoftWebDriver.exe should be pre-installed in an elevated command prompt executing: dism /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

1. Shouldn't the `webdrivermanager` dowbload and install it for me?
2. How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
WebDriverManagerException: MicrosoftWebDriver.exe should be pre-installed in an elevated command prompt executing: dism /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

...implies that the **WebDriverManager** won't be able to install the latest version of **MicrosoftWebDriver** binary in the process to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Microsoft Edge Browser** session.

---

As you are using **Microsoft EdgeHTML 18** as per the documentation in [Microsoft WebDriver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/):

> Microsoft WebDriver for Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML) versions 18 and 19 is a Windows Feature on Demand which ensures that it’s always up to date automatically and enables some new ways to get Microsoft WebDriver.

### Steps

To configure you will have to enable Developer Mode:

```
Go to Settings > Update and Security > For Developer and then select "Developer mode".
```

To install run **Microsoft Edge version 18** through an elevated command prompt:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

**Note**: When installing *MicrosoftWebDriver* through the `DISM` command, by default the webdriver is installed within the following sub-directories:

- 64 bit:

  ```
  C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
  ```
- 32 bit:

  ```
  C:\\Windows\\System32\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
  ```

---

### tl; dr

As per [Microsoft Edge Developer Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide):

> EdgeHTML 18 includes the following new and updated features shipped in the current release of the Microsoft Edge platform, as of the [Windows 10 October 2018 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-build-17763) (10/2018, Build 17763). For changes in specific [Windows Insider](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/) Preview builds, see the [Microsoft Edge Changelog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/changelog/) and [What's New in EdgeHTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/whats-new).