# Python (Selenium) with MS Edge browser: 'Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, ...) "Microsoft Web Driver has stopped working"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

Every time I run my python code, the Edge browser opens but does not load the URL. Then Windows system displays a dialog saying:

> Microsoft Web Driver has stopped working.
>
> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

My Python code: (Running on PyCharm):

```
# Locate the web driver for Edge browser
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path = 'C:/Users/username/webdrivers/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')

# Open the website
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Warning/Error Message from PyCharm:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "02042020.py", line 14, in
>   
>       driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path = 'C:/Users/username/webdrivers/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')   File
>   "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py",
>   line 61, in **init**
>       RemoteWebDriver.**init**(   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 157, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 252, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 319, in execute
>       response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)   File
>   "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py",
>   line 374, in execute
>       return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py",
>   line 402, in _request
>       resp = http.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)   File
>   "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py",
>   line 79, in request
>       return self.request_encode_body(   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py",
>   line 171, in request_encode_body
>       return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py",
>   line 330, in urlopen
>       response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 719, in urlopen
>       retries = retries.increment(   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
>   line 400, in increment
>       raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py",
>   line 734, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 665, in urlopen
>       httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 421, in _make_request
>       six.raise_from(e, None)   File "", line 3, in raise_from   File
>   "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
>   line 416, in _make_request
>       httplib_response = conn.getresponse()   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1322, in getresponse
>       response.begin()   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 303, in begin
>       version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 264, in _read_status
>       line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")   File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py",
>   line 669, in readinto
>       return self._sock.recv_into(b)
>
> **urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054,
>   None))**

Environment details:

- Edge web driver version: **Release 17134 Version: 6.17134 | Microsoft
  Edge version supported: 17.17134**   (downloaded from:
  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)
- Selenium Version: **3.141.0**
- Microsoft Edge Browser Version: **Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363**

I tried troubleshooting but it didn't work.

My troubleshooting:

Enable Developer Mode which will install the appropriate version of WebDriver. On Windows:

```
Settings > Update & Security > For developers > select "Developer Mode".
```

Running CMD as administrator to install via DISM :

> DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability
>   /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0

It says:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Image Version: 10.0.18363.592

[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.
```

I repeated these steps many times but it never worked. I downloaded web driver for Chrome and switched my Python code to run with Chrome browser and it worked. Unfortunately, the problem is that for this particular task, Microsoft Edge is the required browser. Can someone please advise? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this issue occurs because you're using the Microsoft WebDriver version not matching the Microsoft Edge browser version. As far as I know, when we install the Microsoft Edge webdriver via DISM, by default, we could find the webdriver from the following folders:

```
"C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"
```

and

```
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe",
```

You could check it and try to use this path in your code.

Comment: I replaced the path according to your suggestion and issue is resolved now. Thanks you very much. My up vote is not shown because I'm a new user on here. Your answer directly helps.

Comment: Congratulation. I suggest you to try to mark this answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score -1):

This error message...

> urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.',
>   ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
>
> Microsoft Web Driver has stopped working.
>
> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will
>   close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

...implies that the *MicrosoftWebDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Microsoft Edge Browser** session.

---

### Analysis

This error can occur due to numerous factors and some of the probhable causes and solutions are as follows:

- You need to pass the *absolute path* of *MicrosoftWebDriver* through the *key* `executable_path` in either of the ways:

  - Within double quotes, escaping the back slashes:

    ```
    driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="C://Users//username//webdrivers//MicrosoftWebDriver.exe")
    ```
  - Within single quotes and front slashes, preceeded with the raw (`r`) switch:

    ```
    driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'C:\Users\username\webdrivers\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe')
    ```
- This error is also observed when there is **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using interms of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) client version, [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) variant version and *Web Browser* version. See [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799251/urllib3-exceptions-protocolerror-connection-aborted-error10054-an-exist/51799372#51799372).
- You are using:

  - Edge web driver version: Release 17134 Version: 6.17134
  - Microsoft Edge version supported: 17.17134
  - Microsoft Edge Browser Version: Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363
- As per [Microsoft Edge Developer Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide):

> EdgeHTML 18 includes the following new and updated features shipped in the current release of the Microsoft Edge platform, as of the [Windows 10 October 2018 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-build-17763) (10/2018, Build 17763). For changes in specific [Windows Insider](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/) Preview builds, see the [Microsoft Edge Changelog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/changelog/) and [What's New in EdgeHTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/whats-new).

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- Edge web driver version is upgraded to: Release **17763**

---

### Additional Steps

- Enable Developer Mode which will install the appropriate version of WebDriver.

  ```
  Open Settings app > Go to Update & Security > For Developer and then select "Developer Mode".
  ```
- You can also install a standalone version of WebDriver in one of two ways:

  - Search "Manage optional features" from Start, then select "Add a Feature", "WebDriver".
  - Install via DISM by running the following command in an elevated command prompt:

    ```
    DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
    ```

**Note**: When installing *MicrosoftWebDriver* through the `DISM` command, by default the webdriver is installed within the following sub-directories:

- 64 bit:

  ```
  C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
  ```
- 32 bit:

  ```
  C:\\Windows\\System32\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Microsoft Web Driver has stopped working. A problem cause the program to stop working correctly error using EdgeDriver and Microsoft Edge in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471353/microsoft-web-driver-has-stopped-working-a-problem-cause-the-program-to-stop-wo/59473613#59473613)
- [MicrosoftWebDriver.exe should be pre-installed in an elevated command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447561/microsoftwebdriver-exe-should-be-pre-installed-in-an-elevated-command-prompt/59447890#59447890)

Comment: "Ensure that: Edge web driver version is upgraded to: Release 17763" - Could you please elaborate how to upgrade the driver? The latest version found is Release 17134 (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)